# AgGridReact style issue - Header under the cells

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

For some reason when I do add domLayout={'autoHeight'}  the header is showing, but the rows have one space between each row!
If I remove that autoheight, the rows are okay and under eachother no issues, but the Header of the table is under the table first row....
I did play with the height of the DIV around it, from fixed to 100%... no luck.

Any way?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. It seems to be working fine in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-size/#example-auto-height

Comment: please see bbelow:

Answer (score 0):

```
 [![<div
                    id="myGrid"
                    style={{
                        height: '100%',
                        width: '100%',
                    }}
                    className="ag-theme-balham-dark"
                >
                        <AgGridReact                            
                                columnDefs={columnDefs}               
                                rowData={ ...}
                                onGridReady={...}
                                onCellValueChanged={...}
                                onRowValueChanged={...}
                                toolPanelSuppressSideButtons={true}
                                enableColResize={true}
                                allowContextMenuWithControlKey={false} 
                                animateRows={true}    
                                domLayout= 'autoHeight'
                                getRowNodeId={this.getRowNodeId}
                                getContextMenuItems={this.getMyContextMenuItems.bind(this)}
                                             
                                overlayNoRowsTemplate={
                                    '<span style="color:dimgray;font-weight:bold"></span>'
                                  }
                            />                             
                   
                   </div>][![1\]][1]][1]
```

[image]